# Why can't I name a JavaScript function 'function'?

Tags: javascript, function

I have an input button and when the user clicks it's supposed to change background. What's wrong here?

```
<input type="button" value="" onclick="function()" id="sqr1" />

<script>

var vsqr1 = document.getElementById("sqr1");

function function() {
    vsqr1.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
}


</script>
```

Comment: `function` is a keyword you cannot use it as function name.
use different name like `changeColor` etc..

Comment: imagine naming your dog **"where is"**, whenever you ask anyone where is where is, you think they will understand you? no they wont. and javascript wont understand you either if you name a function function.

Comment: I just laughed when I saw the title of the post. :) My five 5cents, some of the most horrible code I've evern seen was written in javascript. I am at least glad that function cannot be used to name a function! :D You are feeling very medidative I suppose, to  pose such a question. I would suggest try writting it in italian, :) you-ll be able to make a function called function - but in a different language.

Answer (score 4):

`function` is not a valid name for a function; change your code to this:

```
<input type="button" value="" onclick="changeColor()" id="sqr1" />

<script>

var vsqr1 = document.getElementById("sqr1");

function changeColor() {
    vsqr1.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Several people already have the right answer here already, but to expand the explanation:

**What's a Reserved Word?**

Most programming languages set aside (or 'reserve') a short list of words and don't allow them to be used as variable names. Sometimes these are also called 'keywords'.

**Why Do They Exist?**

These have been given a special meaning in a programming language and the compiler or interpreter watches for specifically in order to parse your code. In addition, using these words as variable names would make code very hard to read for humans! (One could in theory design a language that required no reserved words, but it would complicate the implementation of the parser as well as making for some confusing code)

**Where CAN Reserved Words Be Used?**

In JavaScript, you can't use a keyword as a variable name, but you CAN use it as the name of an object property. So for instance,

```
var delete = {foo: 3}; // Forbidden
var foo = {delete: 3}; // Allowed
```

**What Are the Reserved Words in Javascript?**

As of the ECMAscript 6 spec, the [reserved words (keywords)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords) in JavaScript are:

- await
- break
- case
- class
- catch
- const
- continue
- debugger
- default
- delete
- do
- else
- enum
- export
- extends
- finally
- for
- function
- if
- import
- in
- instanceof
- let
- new
- return
- super
- switch
- this
- throw
- try
- typeof
- var
- void
- while
- with
- yield

Answer (score 1):

'function' is a reserved word.  You cannot use it for a function name.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call a function function since when you then do onclick= function() it looks like an anonymous function (where you would put the script in line), rename the function to something more meaningful and it will work :-)